# SQL filter rows based on multiple condition and get the matching records with active records

Tags: sql-server

Continuation from here [SQL filter rows based on multiple condition and get the matching records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676284/sql-filter-rows-based-on-multiple-condition-and-get-the-matching-records/52676604?noredirect=1#comment92286934_52676604)

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e20a7ec1ce1642565cf5b830d288e978

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER TABLE
(
    CUSTOMERID INT,
    CUSTOMERNAME NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @ORDER TABLE
(
    ORDERID INT,
    CUSTOMERID INT,
    ISSPECIALORDER INT,
    SPECIALORDERID INT
)

DECLARE @SPECIALORDERDTL TABLE
(
    SPECIALORDERID INT,
    SPECIALORDERDATAID INT
)

DECLARE @SPECIALORDERDATA TABLE
(
    SPECIALORDERDATAID INT,
    SPECIALORDERMASTERID INT,
    ISACTIVE BIT
)

INSERT INTO @CUSTOMER VALUES 
(100,'CUSTOMER1'),
(200,'CUSTOMER2'),
(300,'CUSTOMER3'),
(400,'CUSTOMER4`enter code here`')

INSERT INTO @ORDER VALUES 
(1,100,0,1),
(2,100,1,1),
(3,100,1,2),
(4,200,0,1),
(5,200,1,1),
(6,200,1,4),
(7,300,1,5),
(8,400,1,6)

INSERT INTO @SPECIALORDERDTL VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,4)

INSERT INTO @SPECIALORDERDATA VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,2,0),(5,2,1) -- 2 a special order

SELECT  C.CUSTOMERID,C.CUSTOMERNAME
from @Customer c
where exists (select * from @ORDER o where o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
and not exists (
select * 
from @ORDER O
LEFT JOIN @SPECIALORDERDTL SO ON SO.SPECIALORDERID = O.SPECIALORDERID
LEFT JOIN @SPECIALORDERDATA SOD ON SO.SPECIALORDERDATAID = SOD.SPECIALORDERDATAID
WHERE (SO.SPECIALORDERID IS NULL 
or SOD.SPECIALORDERMASTERID = 2 --AND O.ISSPECIALORDER =0
) AND O.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
);
```

For an entry if it is deleted we are making isactive as 0 and if again a new entry is added it will be 1. So if special order id is 2 and inactive I would like to show those records too.

> Edit

Here is my data for only single customer

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER TABLE
(
    CUSTOMERID INT,
    CUSTOMERNAME NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @ORDER TABLE
(
    ORDERID INT,
    CUSTOMERID INT,
    ISSPECIALORDER INT,
    SPECIALORDERID INT
)

DECLARE @SPECIALORDERDTL TABLE
(
    SPECIALORDERID INT,
    SPECIALORDERDATAID INT
)

DECLARE @SPECIALORDERDATA TABLE
(
    SPECIALORDERDATAID INT,
    SPECIALORDERMASTERID INT,
    ISACTIVE BIT
)

INSERT INTO @CUSTOMER VALUES 
(100,'CUSTOMER1'),
(200,'CUSTOMER2'),
(300,'CUSTOMER3'),
(400,'CUSTOMER4')

INSERT INTO @ORDER VALUES 
(1,100,0,1),
(2,100,1,1),
(3,100,1,2),
(4,100,0,1),
(5,100,1,1),
(6,100,1,4),
(7,100,1,5)

INSERT INTO @SPECIALORDERDTL VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,4),(5,5)

INSERT INTO @SPECIALORDERDATA VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,2,0) -- 2 a special order

SELECT  C.CUSTOMERID,C.CUSTOMERNAME
from @Customer c
where exists (select * from @ORDER o where o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
and not exists (
select * 
from @ORDER O
LEFT JOIN @SPECIALORDERDTL SO ON SO.SPECIALORDERID = O.SPECIALORDERID
LEFT JOIN @SPECIALORDERDATA SOD ON SO.SPECIALORDERDATAID = SOD.SPECIALORDERDATAID
WHERE (SO.SPECIALORDERID IS NULL 
or SOD.SPECIALORDERMASTERID = 2 --AND O.ISSPECIALORDER =0
) AND O.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
);
```

If you see `@SPECIALORDERDATA` I have my last as inactive so I would like to display that record. Obviously what I need is if the last record in `@SPECIALORDERDATA` for the matching customer is active I need to hide else show. If  there is an entry `(6,2,1)` then I need to hide the customer in this case

Comment: I don't understand "continuing" question.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Looks more like a task than a question. Same as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For this added condition, with my answer to the previous question you only have to add on that condition to the case expression:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.CUSTOMERNAME
FROM @CUSTOMER As C
JOIN @ORDER O 
    ON C.CUSTOMERID = O.CUSTOMERID
JOIN @SPECIALORDERDTL SO 
    ON O.SPECIALORDERID = SO.SPECIALORDERID
JOIN @SPECIALORDERDATA SOD
    ON SO.SPECIALORDERDATAID = SOD.SPECIALORDERDATAID
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMERID, C.CUSTOMERNAME
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN SOD.SPECIALORDERMASTERID = 2 OR SOD.ISACTIVE = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Hi Zohar then it will get that order which is inactive like let us say I have 3 rows with 0,0, and 1 as 1 is active it should not get but as per your query it will get the 0 rows too

Comment: `(4,2,0),(5,2,1)` 5 is my latest so it should not get the customer associated.

Comment: I'm kinda lost here.. Please edit your question with the expected output from the sample data you posted.

Comment: I don't need another set of sample data, I need to see the expected results of the first set of sample data....

Comment: Ok so as said I need customer1 info

Comment: Note I will have created date too if in case required

Comment: Here is the fiddle with your query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac0bdff89d100f84093a4b7f461c2c44

Comment: I am not getting data as required

Comment: I need customer1 information should be displayed, and if I have a row as follow `INSERT INTO @SPECIALORDERDATA VALUES(6,2,1) -- 2 a special order` then it should not display customer1 as there is an active record with 6

Comment: Let me just see if I understand the requirements. You want to get the CustomerID and CustomerName of a customer, if they have an order with `SPECIALORDERMASTERID` = 2, or if they have an order with `IsActive` = 0. Is that correct?

Comment: If the customer has a special order and if it is active i need to hide that customer, if not I need to show

Comment: My table is like a transaction table if I delete it will update the entry with 0, if I add a new entry will be added with 1 in my @SPECIALORDERDATA

Comment: So you want only customers where `SPECIALORDERMASTERID = 2 and IsActive = 0`?

Comment: Yes but as I said there will be multiple entries @SPECIALORDERDATA so I would like to get the latest and check if that is active/inactive and accordingly I need to show

Comment: If u see my data here the latest is inactive so it should display https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa84693d2c4dce5774a6664b86a9125b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181488/discussion-between-dorababu-meka-and-zohar-peled).